# How do you evaluate a password input as string in java?

Tags: java, string, input, passwords

I'm supposed to evaluate a password input a string, and then generate a password and return it as a string. Can someone show me an example of how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly intending to do?You should be more clear and specific.Your objective 
is a bit obscure to me.If you want to input a password in the form of asterisk("*") and
display it in the form of plain text,I may help you.Is that what you want?If it is,you 
can try this code given below.
Are you familiar with swing?Then,I should suggest you to try the following code:-

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Pass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JPasswordField jp=new JPasswordField(16);
JPanel p=new JPanel();
JButton b=new JButton("Go-->");

String gs="";
Pass(){
    super("Enter password:-");
    jp.setEchoChar('*');
    p.add(jp);



    p.add(b);
    b.addActionListener(this);
    setSize(200,200);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);


}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==b)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,new String(jp.getPassword()));

}}
public static void main(String args[])
{try{
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch(Exception jkjk){}
    new Pass();
}
}
```